# Automatic version numbering for iOS Xamarin project in Azure Pipelines

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, xamarin.ios

For my project (Mobile iOS application, based on Xamarin) I have set up Azure Pipelines build process.
I would like to automatically increase and set the ipa-file version for every build.

Upon searching the Internet I have found [an article](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/automatic-build-numbering-with-xamarin) that advises to add the following code to the ios project .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" $(SetVersion) == true ">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(AssemblyPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyInfo" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <VersionNumber>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(%(AssemblyInfo.Version), `[^.][^.]*.[^.]*.[^.]*`))</VersionNumber>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Resources/Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleVersion']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(BuildNumber)" />
    <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Resources/Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleShortVersionString']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(VersionNumber)" />
```

I set version number manually and as I don't need the assembly version number I have added this simplified code to my iosProject.csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" $(SetVersion) == true ">
        <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleVersion']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(BuildNumber)" />
        <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleShortVersionString']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(VersionNumber).$(BuildNumber)" />
  </Target>
```

In my azure-pipelines.yml file I have the following command line with hardcoded values (just for debugging purposes) for msbuild call:

```
variables:
    mobileProjectMSbuildArgumentsForIOS: "/p:SetVersion=true /p:VersionNumber=1.0 /p:BuildNumber=34 /bl:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build_iOS.binlog"
```

As you can see, SetVersion is `true`, VersionNumber is `1.0` and BuildNumber is `44`.

Tasks to make the build and generate binary log are as follows:

```
  - task: XamariniOS@2
    inputs:
      solutionFile: '**/*iOS.csproj'
      signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
      signingProvisioningProfileID: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'          
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      msbuildArguments: "$(mobileProjectMSbuildArgumentsForIOS)"
      outputDirectory: "$(outputDirectory)"
      packageApp: true
      args: /p:IpaPackageDir="$(outputDirectory)"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish binary log'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'Binary log'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

But when the project has been built using pipelines, the build is green, but:

1. The version of the ipa-file has not set to the expected `1.0.34`, it has old value, that was set manually in `.plist` file in the project.
2. binary log is not being generated. upon running task to publish the binary log I get the message:

> ##[warning]Directory '/Users/runner/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'Binary log'.

My questions:

Why XmlPoke does not work for ios.csproj file, even `SetVersion` is set to `true`?

Why binary log is not being generated?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found you had mistakes in XamariniOS@2 task. Fields `msbuildArguments` And `outputDirectory` are fields for [Xamarin.Android task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xamarin-android?view=azure-devops). They donot exist for [Xamarin.iOS task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xamarin-ios?view=azure-devops)

So you can try moving `/p:IpaPackageDir="$(outputDirectory)"` And `outputDirectory: "$(outputDirectory)"` to your `mobileProjectMSbuildArgumentsForIOS` variable.

```
variables:
    mobileProjectMSbuildArgumentsForIOS: "/p:OutputPath=$(outputDirectory) /p:IpaPackageDir="$(outputDirectory)" /p:SetVersion=true /p:VersionNumber=1.0 /p:BuildNumber=34 /bl:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build_iOS.binlog"
```

Then assign the msbuildArguments to `args` fields: `args: "$(mobileProjectMSbuildArgumentsForIOS)"`

See below changed the XamariniOS@2 task:

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
    inputs:
      solutionFile: '**/*iOS.csproj'
      signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
      signingProvisioningProfileID: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'          
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      args: "$(mobileProjectMSbuildArgumentsForIOS)"
      packageApp: true
```